# Is there a way to see my remaining votes?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

Like the title says, Is there a way to see my remaining votes? Something like:

```
-- Votes left today
```

Or cast today?

```
-- Votes cast today
```

I know I can see it at the  Suffrage, Vox populi or something badge, but I've already earned those badges so I can't view it there. And I know also that I can see my `votes` page, but It's hard to count the hours and count my votes.

Is there any way to see my votes cast today, or votes remaining today?

Comment: I go through the comment votes limit often; I really wish there was a message for comment votes similar to the ones that exist for post votes.

Comment: There was a comment vote limit?! How much?

Comment: @ppwater 40 per day

Comment: At the moment you cant see remaining votes. However you could go to your activity page and see how many votes you have cast today. Then subtract it from 40.

Comment: @cornonthecob Oh, so it's same as post vote limit. and thanks for the information.